# Android: Forcing a MapView to redraw

Tags: android

I've found that after changing the overlays on a `MapView`, the changes aren't seen until the user moves the Map, causing a redraw.  Is there a way to force this redraw?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your Overlay, keep a reference to the MapView.  Then when you want to force a redraw, call:

```
mMapView.invalidate();
```

Alternatively, if you're not in the UI thread, you can call this:

```
mMapView.postInvalidate();
```